# How do you align a system of equations?

Tags: latex, mathjax

I want these equations to line up so that all variables and operators go straight down. I've tried a few different techniques but haven't been able to get it to work.

[image]

Nope:

```
\begin{align*}
  x+y+z=1 \\ 
  x+y+z=\frac{5}{2} \\ 
  x+y+z=5
\end{align*}
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8L4t3ehf/1/).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `&=` to signify to align with the equals:

```
\begin{align*}
  x+y+z &= \,1 \\ 
  x+y+z &= \frac{5}{2} \\ 
  x+y+z &= \,5
\end{align*}
```

[image: aligned and spaced over a tiny bit]

You can use these in math mode:

> ```
> \; - a thick space
> \: - a medium space
> \, - a thin space     <-- used this here in front of the simple numbers
> \! - a negative thin space
> ```

Source: http://www.emerson.emory.edu/services/latex/latex_119.html

You can reread about `align*` environment f.e. here: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Advanced_Mathematics#align_and_align*

Comment: Is there anything I can do about the spacing of the column to the right of the equals sign?

Comment: On my screen it looks like the 5/2 is vertically to the right of the 1 and 5 that are above and below it.

Comment: If it's possible, perhaps a better way is to center-align the right column? Otherwise, what if the font has a larger or smaller line-width to the left and right of the `5/2` ?

Comment: Now I don't like it because you can't tell the rows apart. But this works. Thanks!

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb how would you do it? post as answer, I am a latex amateur :)

Answer (score 19):

There is a package `systeme` for systems of linear equations with automatic alignment of the variables and values - it even detects the variables for you.

In the standard set-up use you would just write

```
\begin{equation*}
  \systeme{
  x+y+z = 1,
  x+y+z = \frac{5}{2},
  x+y+z = 5
  }
\end{equation*}
```

[image: Sample output]

or

```
\begin{equation*}
  \systeme{
  3x +7z = 20,
  y - 17z = -3,
  24x + 15y = 7
  }
\end{equation*}
```

[image: Second general example]

which may or may not suit your taste.  The bracket can removed by specifying empty delimiters by preceding the `\systeme` command with

```
\sysdelim..
```

(`.` is an empty place holder, `\sysdelim` needs two as it specifies a left and a right delimiter).
To make the fraction bigger you can use `\dfrac` from the `amsmath` package (which you are already loading), but then you have to help with the line spacing:

[image: Second sample]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,systeme}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
  \systeme{
  x+y+z = 1,
  x+y+z = \frac{5}{2},
  x+y+z = 5
  }
\end{equation*}

No delimeter, displaystyle fraction and line spacing
\begin{equation*}
  \sysdelim..\systeme{
  x+y+z = 1,
  x+y+z = \dfrac{5}{2}\rule[-3ex]{0pt}{7ex},
  x+y+z = 5
  }
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Alternatively extra spacing can be added between all lines via the command `\syslineskipcoeff` which is a scaling factor:

[image: Third sample]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,systeme}

\begin{document}

No delimeter, displaystyle fraction and line spacing
\begin{equation*}
  \sysdelim..\syslineskipcoeff{2}\systeme{
  x+y+z = 1,
  x+y+z = \dfrac{5}{2},
  x+y+z = 5
  }
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @ScumCoder Not as far as I know.  There is only a French manual on CTAN, but this displays fairly clearly examples of usage with different options.

Comment: Never thought I'd use français in les mathematiques, but hey I'm glad I learned french.

Comment: You can specify the variable names as in `\systeme[xyz]{ ... }` in case you have other terms in the equations you do not wish to align to (e.g. `\systeme[xyz]{ax + y + z = 1, x + y + z = 2}` -- otherwise systeme will treat `ax` and `x` as different terms rather than aligning the `x`'s).

Answer (score 4):

Simply adding `&` before each line results in the desired output.

```
\begin{align*}
  &x+y+z=1 \\ 
  &x+y+z=\frac{5}{2} \\ 
  &x+y+z=5
\end{align*}
```

Comment: Is placing the & at the start a shorthand? As I understand it & tells it you want that part aligned vertically but I want each term aligned vertically.

Comment: Placing & at the beginning has no effect other than adding an empty column on the left. Try to align equations having *different* lengths before =, in your example = signs are already aligned naturally, this makes you think your solution is working.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution modeled after Yossi Farjoun's second answer in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4273/align-two-inequalities.
It requires a horizontal space adjustment between the two columns with `\!\!\:`. The `\vphantom` command synchronizes their vertical spacings.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}  x+y+z &=\\ x+y+z &= \vphantom{\frac{5}{2}}\\ x+y+z &= \end{aligned}\!\!\:
\begin{gathered} 1       \\ \frac{5}{2}                    \\ 5        \end{gathered}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image: 1]